# Facebook Graph api feed request not showing older posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook Graph API in C# and I'm trying to read all of a users wall updates.  "feed" works well (with limit=5000 giving me everything).  I am seeing all the users posts for this years, but only other people's posts prior to this.  Does anyone know if there is a parameter I am missing, or is there a better api item to use?

I have the access token, and I am getting all my posts for this year.  When I use the feed url in a browser, I see the same results; all my posts for this year, then only other people's before this.

Answer (score 0):

For querying the user's feed, you will want to use `me/home` and for the posts that the user has made to his own feed (or of items where friends have sent it "to" the user), use `me/feed`.

You can also do a bunch of filtering off of the FQL stream table.  This query should give you  only feed items posted by the user.

`SELECT post_id, viewer_id, app_id, source_id,actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() and actor_id=me()`